# js: default function of an object

Tags: javascript

I have object with functions, and I can call this functions like this **`myobject.myobjectfunction()`**

But can I have default function which will be called like this **`myobject()`**

```
let cat = {
  say: function(value) {
    console.log(value)
  },
  sit: function() {
    console.log("cat sit")
  }
  // default: function() {
  //  console.log(meow)
  // }
}
cat.say("Hi") //  Hi

// cat() // Meow
```

Comment: @Seblor — Functions are a type of object, so it can.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't have a "default" function. An object is either a function or it isn't. You can make `cat` a function in the first place and then add additional properties to it.

```js
function cat() {
  console.log("Meow");
}
cat.say = function(value) {
  console.log(value)
};
cat.sit = function() {
  console.log("cat sit")
}
cat.say("Hi") //  Hi
cat() // Meow
```

Comment: Yeah. You right. 
But  can I create a "default" function with additional properties right away?

Comment: @rendom — I demonstrated how in my answer.

Comment: in your answer we declare function and then adding additional properties. But can we do it together?

Comment: That is "together". Nothing else can run between the statements (because they all run on the same event loop).